# How do I rotate a group of objects?

Tags: animation

I have a group of objects, 3 cylinders and 2 text objects. I am able to rotate a single cylinder by adding a rotation keyframe on scene 1 and setting the z rotation to 359 and adding a keyframe on the last frame.

How do I do this for a group of objects?

Comment: Do you want to rotate all objects around a common center, or around their respective centers?

Comment: around a common center

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple options:

## Parenting:

You could [Parent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/editing/parenting.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) the other objects to an empty or another object, and then rotate that empty/object.

## Keyframe all the objects:

Select all the grouped objects by selecting one and the pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Group*, then insert keyframes for them all by pressing <kbd>I</kbd>*> Rotation*.

Comment: Latter way of adding individual keyframes wouldn't really work, the objects would rotate in place without location keyframes, and even with keying location they'd move linearly. Parenting would be recommanded.

Comment: @hjaarnio Your right. However it would work if you used *LocRot* keyframes and rotated in the 3D view with R using *median* our *bounding box center* as the rotation point.

Comment: I Parented all my objects to an empty object - seemed to work fine.