# How do I rotate a group of objects around their respective centers?

Tags: groups

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7330/how-do-i-rotate-a-group-of-objects) asks about rotating a group of objects around a common center. I want to rotate a group of objects around their respective centers, is that possible?

Comment: At the bottom of the 3D view, you have a button which allows to choose the pivot center. Set it to 'individual origins'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal behavior is like this

[image]

Set the menu as below:

[image]

You will get look like this:
[image]

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the **Pivot point** to **"Individual origins"**