# How to chance radii of many cylinders at the same time?

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms

I want to change radii of the cylinders without moving each one.

[image]

Now the radius of each cylinder is 0,6cm, I want to make them 0,13cm.

Is is possible?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87757/how-do-i-rotate-a-group-of-objects-around-their-respective-centers/87761#87761

Comment: As Josh points out in his answer .. if you know you're going to want your objects to be identical, it would always be a good idea to Alt-D make them instances of a single mesh, rather than Shift-D, copies of it..

Answer (score 3):

If they are equal, you can select all of them, Ctrl L Link object data, then if you modify one, every other will be modified as well. Press U to turn back to single user.

To vary the radius of the cylinders without affecting loc and rot, choose the "normal" transform orientation, select the top of one cylinder and click this plus button to create a new custom transform orientation, call it "face normal".

[image]

Then choose face normal as active transform orientation, select all vertices of one cylinder and press  S Shift Z Z.

[image]

Comment: But if i change the scale or delta scale the cylinder will move. I don't that the cylinder stay in the same place

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: 'Normal' is one of the orientation presets .. you don't have to select it to create a Custom Orientation from a face. Z will always be the vector which is the mean normal to your selection of 3 or more vertices (face or not) , Y the vector between 2.

Comment: @Robin Betts you are right, but this way it works even in object mode with rotations applied.

Comment: I'm with you on the Custom Orientation.. was just thinking you don't have to go through 'Normal' to create it ... or .. I was hoping for a whole new dimension to CO's which I hadn't found yet :) Not a big thing.

Comment: @joshsanfelici perfect!