# How to rotate many objects around their individual origins?

Tags: transforms, groups, origin

I have got about 500 planes in my scene that were generated by an addon. But the addon generates them in a horizontal orientation, whereas I need them in a vertical orientation. One object, or two, I would just rotate one by one. But, doing  that for 500+ planes takes forever. How can I rotate them all at once ?

I tried selecting all shapes and then setting `Pivot Point` to `Individual Origins`, as suggested in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87757/how-do-i-rotate-a-group-of-objects-around-their-respective-centers), but that didn't help - still, all planes were rotated around the world origin.

Comment: maybe your pivot point of your objects is at the world origin? so before rotation select  all and use object -> Origin to geometry. if this doesn't help, please provide blend file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be, as @Chris suggests, that these are separate objects, and all of their origins are at World 0. In that case, their 'Individual Origins' are all at the same place, if you rotate in Object Mode.

However, in Edit Mode, 'Individuals' are islands of geometry, and their origins are at their centers.. so  Edit Mode, with all selected,  might do it for you.

[image]